# Cannot Properly Print Contents of Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, segmentation-fault

I have some C++ code where I'm taking input from a user, adding it to a vector splitting the string by delimiter, and for debugging purposes, printing the vector's contents. However, the program only prints the first location of the vector, and then none of the rest.
main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

//Custom headers
#include "splitting_algorithm.hpp"
#include "mkdir.hpp"
#include "chdir.hpp"
#include "copy.hpp"

//Used to get and print the current working directory
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string command;

    //Gets current working directory
    char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //Placeholder for arguments
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        cout<<string(argv[i])<<endl;
    }

    //Begin REPL code
    while (true)
    {
        //Prints current working directory
        cout<<cCurrentPath<<": ";
        cin>>command;

        vector<string> tempCommand = strSplitter(command, " ");

        //Exit command
        if(string(tempCommand[0])=="exit")
        {
            for(int i=0; i<tempCommand.size(); ++i){
                cout << tempCommand[i] << ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

splitting_algorithm.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> strSplitter(string command, string delim)
{
    vector<string> commandVec;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    string delimiter = delim;

    while ((pos = command.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
    {
        token = command.substr(0, pos);
        commandVec.push_back(token);
        command.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    commandVec.push_back(command);

    return commandVec;
}
```

Entering "exit 1 2 3" in the terminal returns:

`exit /home/tay/Git/batch-interpreter: /home/tay/Git/batch-interpreter: /home/tay/Git/batch-interpreter: /home/tay/Git/batch-interpreter:`

(The output has no newlines in it)
Why is this occurring?

Comment: Your `strSplitter` algorithm would be a lot more efficient, if you didn't erase already read data. You can use `command.find(delimiter, pos + 1)` to search from the position onwards.

Comment: Really? Thanks, I never knew I could do that!

Comment: Where specifically would I put that line, should I replace `command.erase()`?

Comment: You can remove `command.erase` altogether (and by extension you can pass `command` as a constant reference). Add `size_t prev_pos = 0;` at the top of the function, replace the condition by `pos = command.find(delimiter, prev_pos + 1)` and inside the loop `token = command.substr(prev_pos, pos);`. Instead of the `erase` just do a `prev_pos = pos;`. That way you will basically walk over the whole string, picking up the tokens.

Comment: I tried that, and it completely ignores everything besides the first substring, but I probably put it in wrong. I hate to ask this, but could you post a more complete code showing what you mean?

Comment: There you are, was a bit more complicated than anticipated ;) http://ideone.com/E0aJS5

Comment: The code only works if I remove `const&` from the function, otherwise, it says undefined reference. Is that because you're using C++14 and I'm using C++98?

Comment: You just have to update your header too :)

Comment: OHHHHHH I feel stupid =P
Sorry to keep asking questions, but does the `const& char` make much of a difference over just a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> I have some C++ code where I'm taking input from a user, adding it to a vector splitting the string by delimiter, and for debugging purposes, printing the vector's contents.

And your code does:

```
while (true)
{
    //Prints current working directory
    cout<<cCurrentPath<<": ";

    ///
    /// This line of code reads only one token.
    /// It does not contain multiple tokens.
    /// Perhaps you meant to read an entire line.
    /// 
    cin>>command;

    vector<string> tempCommand = strSplitter(command, " ");

    //Exit command
    if(string(tempCommand[0])=="exit")
    {
        for(int i=0; i<tempCommand.size(); ++i){
            cout << tempCommand[i] << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Change the line

```
cin>>command;
```

to

```
std::getline(std::cin, command);
```

Also, to make the output cleaner, add a line to print a newline.
Add

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

immediately after

```
for(int i=0; i<tempCommand.size(); ++i){
    cout << tempCommand[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: The above code works. Space was causing the problem. use getline and your code will start working

Comment: Doesn't explain the seg-faulting, though.

Comment: The seg faulting was my fault with for loops and not understanding vectors much. I'm removing it from the OP.